# Como colocarle un punto a un sueldo utilizando TO_CHART

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, oracle-12c

Buenas puedo colocar el signo de peso y una coma al sueldo de un empleado utilizando el TO_CHART de esta manera.

```
    SELECT numrut_emp || '-' || dvrut_emp, nombre_emp || ' ' || appaterno_emp || ' ' || 
    apmaterno_emp, TO_CHAR(sueldo_emp, '$9,999,999')
    FROM EMPLEADO
```

Pero a la hora de cambiar las comas por puntos me da error existe alguna forma de lograr insertar puntos a esta función?

Comment: Desea usar "coma" para separar los miles o para indicar decimales?

Comment: ¿que motor de base de datos estas usando? ¿Mysql, t-sql, oracle?

Comment: @AbrahamChan oracle

Comment: @alvalongo lo que quiero es usar puntos las comas si me deja, pero al utilizar puntos me da error

Comment: Parece que buscas un remedio, mas no solucionar un problema de raíz de NLS. A menos que tengas usuarios de un solo lenguaje-país, ¿de cuál?, considerando que no todos los paises utilizan el mismo separador de miles/decimales, incluso hispanoparlantes. Tal vez el problema reside en tu configuración local.

Answer (score 0):

Para formatear número en ORACLE SQL tienes distinto elementos que te ayudan a manejar los elementos de los símbolos de las monedas. En este caso

```
'L' que retorna el símbolo de moneda por defecto definido en NLS_CURRENCY
'G' que retorna el símbolo entero por defecto definido en NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER
'D' que retorna el símbolo decimal por defecto definido en NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER
```

En tu caso el formato quedaría

```
 TO_CHAR(sueldo_emp, 'L9G999G999''NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=".,"')
```

En dado caso de que tus números sean enteros